# in a Drawing application I want to use MVC approach but I have some doubts about Model's task

Tags: model-view-controller

I want to develop a software with MVC approach . I am familiar with MVC and how to implementing it specially with database programs but here is my doubt:

I want to create a graphical application in iPhone which in this case I don't have any other choice except MVC but implementing a 100% MVC sometimes is hard and rules easily can be violated.
I have put my drawing function(calculation) inside View.

I have a controller as usual which is responsible to call the subview(V) and my main class(M)
And my main class(M) doesn't do much for me only storing some numbers and variables in it.

this is where my doubt started :

do I need to transfer the calculation part of drawing to model? the calculation part right now resides in view and the reason for that is I need to access some properties of View like height and width , etc ....
so I decided to put the calculation and drawing inside the view.

please help me to clarify this problem , because I want to practice software engineering using MVC and this is like a self training.

Answer (score 1):

I see this as design issue that you can decide yourself. You can either say that image width/height are part of the picture, and all image attributes would be then returned as absolute X and Y coordinates. Or then you could say that the image is 100% scalable, and the view determines the size it is drawn into, and keep the calculation in the view.